# Angular How to use Component in another Component

Tags: angular, components

I have 2 components, first one is modules/pages/home/home.component
and the second one is modules/pages/home/components/banner
I want to use banner component in home component. when i try to use i get this error

1. If 'app-banner' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-banner' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
   how can i solve this?

Answer (score 4):

1. To use a component "A" this component must be declared in a Module
2. To use a component "A" in another component "B", the two component
   can be declared in the same module or in different module (Imagine
   declare in module "A" and in module "B") but, **in this case**, the
   module "A" must be "export" the component "A", and the module "B"
   must be import the module "A"

In the same module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [AComponent,BComponent,...],
})
export class AllInOneModule {}
```

In different Module

```
//Module "A"
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [AComponent,...],
  exports: [AComponent],
})
export class AModule {}

//Module "B"
@NgModule({
  imports: [AModule...],
  declarations: [BComponent,...],
})
export class BModule {}
```

Comment: i am trying to use banner component in home component & the banner component folder is placed same where the home componet resides

Comment: Has you include in the array `imports` of your AppModule the PagesModule ?

Comment: pages.modules.ts

`import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
;

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PagesRoutingModule } from './pages-routing.module';
import { HowItWorksComponent } from './how-it-works/how-it-works.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './home/components/banner/banner.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent, HowItWorksComponent, BannerComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, PagesRoutingModule],
})
export class PagesModule {}`

Answer (score 1):

From your folder structure it looks like both components should be part of the same module.

So go to `home.module.ts` or whatever `@NgModule` you have, and make sure `app-banner` is part of the `declarations` array.

Alternatively, if `app-banner` is part of separate module, be sure to add that other module inside `home.module`'s `import` array.

Comment: there is no file with name module in home directory

Comment: well in home folder it contains home.component files and in same place i have a folder name components

Answer (score 1):

There should be an `app.module.ts` file in your project, inside it you'll find `@NgModule`, and then there should be `declarations` property (it's an array). Try to insert your `BannerComponent` in there and call your banner component using it's selector in `home.component.html`.

Comment: in app.module.ts i have added the this:
import { BannerComponent } from './modules/pages/home/components/banner/banner.component';

and in ngmodule:     BannerComponent,

but getting same error

Comment: page.module.ts

<br/>

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
;

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PagesRoutingModule } from './pages-routing.module';
import { HowItWorksComponent } from './how-it-works/how-it-works.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './home/components/banner/banner.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent, HowItWorksComponent, BannerComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, PagesRoutingModule],
})
export class PagesModule {}

Comment: app.module.ts


`
import { HomeComponent } from './modules/pages/home/home.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './modules/pages/home/components/banner/banner.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,

  ],

Answer (score 0):

after import and declare the component in app.moudle.ts it works